# Unit test failing after adding framework to framework project

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a framework project that I've added a framework to. The existing project has a test target, since I've added a third party framework I now get the following error:

`Library not loaded: @rpath/JWT.framework/JWT`

I have tried adding the framework to the test target's build phases Link binary with libraries section with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when the app is unable to load a framework at runtime. One cause of this could be that the framework isn't embedded in the built app.

Aside from the *Link Binary With Libraries* build phase, you'll also need to ensure that the framework in question is added to the *Embed Frameworks* build phase in order to ensure it's bundled into the final app.